# iPhone Safari zooming changing from portrait no landscape

Tags: iphone, safari, landscape, portrait

I'm trying to optimize my webpage for mobile browsing, and I'm having problems with iPhone 3GS Safari browser.
It shows the page OK in portrait mode, but when I rotate it to landscape, it just zooms it instead of regrouping.
I've tried meta fixes such as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and variant without "width=device-width" options, but they have no effect.